# Не получается сделать полоски как на картинке

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли реализовать такие полоски(это 1 белая и 2 серые полоски), как на картинке с использованием html/css?

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/642684/262779 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/599036/262779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

мыслите проще, псеводэлементы ::before / ::after вам в помощь

```css
body,html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  background: #EDF2F5;
  padding: 10% 0;
  text-align:center;
}

.wrap .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.wrap::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 31%;
  background: #fff;
  left: 37%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  height: 140%;
  top: -20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>За сколько месяцев окупится ГБО</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```